# Textboxes Obscured by Keyboard

Tags: input, flutter

Very simply, every time I try to use text fields in a list view as the body of a Scaffold and the Text field takes focus, the keyboard appears but the text field then disappears from view.

Is there a particular parameter that I have to set such that the Text field does not disappear?

```
    return new Scaffold(

      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextField()
        ],
      ),

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read about it here 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10826

also a workaround, you can use:
https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/50172e3547e959cba77e2938f2fe5ff5

Comment: Agreed.  Collin Jackson's solution works almost perfectly except when the keyboard is intentionally dismissed by the user and the user clicks/taps again on the field.  Then the keyboard covers the field.  I complemented Collin's solution in the following article: https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/

Comment: with GestureDetector in you ui you can "foucs out" of the textfield for better ux such as OnPress on submit button on the form